# Can't set target of android emulator to Google Api's

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I can make an emulator with Marshmallow. I can see the target (with Google APIs), but when I select that it defaults back to a similar setting but without the Google API's. Without it I get the message to update the google play service.

Settings I choose but shouldn't matter:
Phone, Nexus 5, 4,95", 1080x1920, xxhpdi.
Marshmallow, 23, x86, Android 6.0 (with Google APIs)

The goal is to get by the 'Update Google Play Service' message to test apps on an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

When I create new target with Google APIs 23 using Android Studio —— AVD Manager,I meet the same trouble with you. So I turn off Android Studio,just open AVD Manager only,try to create target with Google APIs,I succeed.
 You can try another way to create new target,command line is a good choice,you can see the log to confirm where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Open SDK Manager , and install Google APIs Intel x86 and google APIs if they re not installed